# Create an offline installation of Visual Studio 2017 RTM

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, visual-studio-2017

With the release of [visual studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/?utm_source=mscom&utm_campaign=msdocs)  in March 7, 2017 (build 26628.04), I didn't find ISO for download but i reached the page [Create an offline installer for Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio)

My question:

Q1: Can  the download  **Resume**  in case of it's interrupted or internet disconnection - or it start from the beginning?

Q2: Is  download program  incrementally download the component?
I means if i downloaded "ManagedDesktop components" by the command:

```
 vs_community.exe --layout e:\vs2017offline --lang en-US --add  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop
```

Then latter downloaded NetCoreTools:

```
  vs_community.exe --layout e:\vs2017offline --lang en-US --add  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools
```

Can download program  avoid re-downloading again a previous components?

Comment: Vote here to request Microsoft make an ISO for VS 2017:  https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/17541385-please-make-iso-files-for-visual-studio-2017

Comment: I have voted. I have that MS make ISO starting from the next release vs2017 update3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the page you [linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio):

> If you want to update your offline installation, run the --layout
>   command again. Make sure to point to the same folder that you used
>   before; this way, only those components that have been updated since
>   you last ran --layout will be downloaded.

My interpretation of that is that only new components will be downloaded.

---

User comments from that page support my interpretation, and also seem to suggest that it supports resuming.

> You can cancel the download at any time.  There is "Resume"
>   capability, but you just isse the command again and it does not
>   download any modules that already unless it has been updated in the
>   meanwhile.  This is how you update the offline tiles: just issue the
>   command again.  So, by using the --add command you can download only a
>   part of the VS2017 features that you want, and defer some of those
>   that may be more exotic for your environment such as mobile or
>   android.  The novel feature of this download method is that it can be
>   incremental.

Comment: You are right. It's smart download, resume, incremental and no duplication. I downloaded part by part desktop,core,web and some tools.~ 2.16GB.

Comment: Yes, it works. Sometimes there is an error, than you have to strip the commandline to load the packages step-by-step.